# VS2015 TypeScript import aliases for AMD

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, amd, r.js

I'm trying to create a Javascript bundle from Typescript sources in Visual Studio 2015 (using Typescript v1.7) using r.js.

My source files are in a 'src' folder under the Project and when I include another .ts in the current module using:

```
import {MyModule} from 'src/package/other/MyModule'
```

it compiles fine. But I now want to specify an alias for the module, e.g.

```
import {MyModule} from 'package/other/MyModule'
```

and use requirejs config to set `paths:['package':'src/package']`. This would allow me to bundle the source files up into a single package and have the AMD references follow this `package/other/....` relationships.

This works fine when manually changing the JS files,
but the VS2015 Typescript compiler doesn't appear to allow this, and returns a `"Cannot find module 'package/other/MyModule'"` error. Is there any way to persuade the TS compiler to treat the 'src' folder as a prefix/alias for imports?

(or am I best just munging the .js files post-compilation?)

Comment: Maybe I do not understand but why not use relative references and let tsc bundle these for you using the "out" option?

Comment: I looked at -out, but r.js seemed to do a better job of dependency management (ensuring that files appear in the order in which they need to be referenced), uglification, and integrates better with module loaders.

I've now managed to just work around it by including a step in the build process to make the includes relative to the src folder. Ideally TSC would have something like the ```-Idir``` option in cpp, but until that time, this does the job.

Comment: I think you're looking for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039, where the TSC and, presumably, Visual Studio, will understand these mappings.  It's a 2.0 feature.